# Get the audio duration using libsndfile

Tags: c++, libsndfile

I created an application using libsndfile and wasapi, it allows playing an audio file slowly and manually with the cursor using QSlider.

I see that libsndfile uses frames, I want to know how to get the duration of this audio file but I can not find it in the documentation of libsndfile and play parts of the audio file using ms.

I managed to make it work with the frames but I want to understand how to do it with the milliseconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects `libsndfile` creates have a `frames()` method that gives you this information. `samplerate()` gives you the sampling rate, so then the duration is:

```
static_cast<double>(frames())/samplerate()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
so if it returns 0.834, that means 834 ms, right?

Comment: yes, exactly. Samplerate is samples per sec, frames are samples, so you get an answer in seconds.